# not in, in statement not working (booking)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have for a long time tried to make an SQL query for checking if a hotel room is available between two dates,  but I can't get it to work (it shows errors on MySQL). It seems that the problem lies in the first part of the statement. The statement checks available room ids that are not in the "booked" table. When I execute the first part of the statement (the code below )it shows an empty column(without room-ids, only column name)  *edit: Mysql didn't update the table, this part of the problem is no fixed*

I'm making a query to show the available rooms between two dates

```
    SELECT rom_id  
FROM
seka2804_hotelbestilling.rom
where
 rom_id  not in (
                     SELECT * FROM seka2804_hotelbestilling.bestilit_rom;
);
```

This is the whole query

```
SELECT rom_id 
                    FROM seka2804_hotelbestilling.rom where romtype_id=$type-rom
                    AND rom_id  NOT IN 
                    (
                    select rom_id
                    from seka2804_hotelbestilling.bestilit_rom 
                    where (innsjekk >= @start and innsjekk < @end)
                    or (utsjekk >= @start and utsjekk < @end))
```

ER- diagram 
image-url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvzDG.jpg

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  What are you trying to do?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: `sql query for checking if an hotel room is availeble between two dates,`->`select rom_id
                    from seka2804_hotelbestilling.bestilit_rom 
                    where (innsjekk >= @start and innsjekk < @end)
                    or (utsjekk >= @start and utsjekk < @end))`

Comment: IN the first piece of code, you have an extra `;` just before the last `)`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: You provide a non-working query, but not a description of what it's ***meant*** to be doing.  As far as I can tell you ***want*** a list of all rooms that are not booked-up between two dates.  But you're not clear on is what to do if a room is booked for ***some*** of the date range you're querying.  What you ***have*** is `WHERE room NOT IN (Rooms where the CheckIn or CheckOut are in the date range)`  If the CheckIn is before that date range and the checkout is after the date range, you don't filter it out.

Comment: You ***probably*** want `NOT IN (SELECT room FROM boookings WHERE CheckIn < @end AND CheckOut > @start)`...  That will exclude rooms that are booked for ***any part*** of the range you are querying.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your *date* filter should go from `outer query` not from `subquery`

```
SELECT rm.rom_id  
FROM seka2804_hotelbestilling.rom rm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM seka2804_hotelbestilling.bestilit_rom 
                  WHERE rom_id = rm.rom_id) AND
      ((innsjekk >= @start and innsjekk < @end) OR
       (utsjekk >= @start and utsjekk < @end));
```